# details for connection string from teradata sql assistent

Tags: teradata

I have access to teradata via the sql assistant. Just curious, can I find details I require for a connection string (e.g. server name to connect to teradata from C#/Power BI) inside the sql assistant.

Comment: The ODBC or .Net Provider connection properties should provide you with the server name to use elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks but where can i find them in sql assistant?

Comment: When you use SQL Assistant and connect using the .Net Provider, the server name available in the Connection Information Dialog. The second field is named `Server`. If you connect using ODBC, after you select your ODBC DSN, the field named `DBC Name or Address` should contain the server name (or IP Address). If all else fails, contact your DBA.

Comment: OK thanks. Maybe I was just expecting an IP or proper URI but we only have a string e.g. bladibla

Comment: Unlike TD Studio (or another client using JDBC), you do not get a URL connection displayed with OBDC or the .Net Provider in SQA.